# Records within a certain month, when Date is saved System.Data.DbType.Date

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

I have searched the similar questions, and tried the SQL query:

```
"SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE strftime('%m', date) = 2";
```

which does not work for me (nothing is returned).

When creating a record, to save a date I use Date picker and then a parameter to a command (in a different place, not relating to the query above):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", System.Data.DbType.Date).Value =this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

Comment: Have you tried use `@date` instead of `date` on your sql query?

Comment: @D-Shih Just tried but that leads to an error. Date is the name of tha column. These two lines are not in the same place.